# How To Use The Orchard CMS Featured Posts Module

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard, still finding my way around it. I've gone through some tutorials to understand the basics.

I want to show a list of featured blog posts, the problem is, I can't figure out how to use the featured posts module located at https://github.com/aranasoft/orchard-featuredposts. I've installed the module, but I can't find a way to access it.

Another option I have in mind is creating a boolean field for Blog Post content type that I can check to mark the post as featured, then display it using projection and query. Before I go this route, I want to know if there's a standard way of doing this.

I am using Orchard 1.10.1

Comment: Do you have any errors under App_Data/logs? Seems the module is created for Orchard 1.7, so you'll probably have to upgrade the .net framework version of the project

Comment: @devqon I couldn't get it to work, ended up using the option of adding a custom checkbox field.